# Vendor/assets in Rails

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, ruby

Trying to connect a template in my application I have move all the files from the /assets to vendor/assets of my application and wrote in application.rb

```
config.assets.paths << Rails.root.join("template_folder")
```

but all the css&js worked only to the index page specified in the routes.rb

```
root to: "pages#index"
```

When I opening pages/index or pages/contact css & js don't work. how can I make them work with others controllers in my application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to mention the added files into `application.css` and `application.js` . Any new files added will have to mentioned in the application file , and also you will have to precompile the assets using `rake:assets precompile` if you are using assets .

Comment: Yes , you will have to do them or else it won't get taken in by the application

Comment: Mention the css files into application.css and js files in application.js